# OpenSSL has just appeared on my homebrew folder

Tags: macos, installation, openssl, homebrew

I've just noticed that a program called `openssl`  appeared in my `/usr/local/Cellar`.

I have **brew** installed on my mac but I've never run:

```
brew -v install openssl
```

Is there anyway **brew** has installed it by itself?

The following programs have been installed via brew:

- astyle
- mercurial
- pypy
- wget

Comment: If it's a pre-requisite of another package, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a dependency for wget. You can verify this by using `brew info wget` and looking at the "Dependencies" part (also online at http://braumeister.org/formula/wget).

You can also verify this by running `brew uses --installed openssl` to see which packages use OpenSSL.